# how to write to a text file using python ?

Tags: python, python-2.6, writetofile

I am trying to output a full for iteration. The output should be in a text file. How should I code for that ?

The output should look like :

> Iteration 1 values --------> val1 < tab > val2 < tab > val3
>
> Iteration 2 values --------> val4 < tab > val5 < tab > val6

This is not much of an information but I don't know where to start , can any1 show me plz ?? At the basic how should I open a text file and try and write using tabs ??

Comment: What are val1, val2, etc? Are these variables? Elements of an array?

Comment: This information is actually provided in the Python documentation.  Start by reading section 7.2: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Well, start by reading the tutorial from the beginning, before asking on SO.

Comment: val1,val2 are just some numeric values , nothing much!

Comment: Please search on Google for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write('\t'.join(numbers))
```

Not really sure what else you mean

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open(filename,"w")
file.write("\t This is tabbed in \n This is a new line")
file.close()
```

Read here about file handling in python 
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files