# Printing a txt file in a def function

Tags: python

I have my `.txt`  file saved as `writing.txt` on my computer and on my project. I want to define a function so that when the user selects `option A`, it prints the text file.

I have tried this with no success

```
def showMembers:
    print (writing.txt)
    writing.txt(close)
```

However, I'm really stuck on how to get it to work.

Comment: Did you try reading any Python resources before posting your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to write to a text file using python ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749224/how-to-write-to-a-text-file-using-python)

Answer (score 2):

The `def` keyword is lower case.

You also need  to [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) the file in the first place to read it. It's recommended to do this through the context manager [with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) so python automatically closes the file once you're done reading it.

Try:

```
def show_members():
    with open('writing.text') as file:
        # Iterate through all lines of the file
        for line in file:
            print(line)

# Call your function
show_members()
```

Comment: I have added the code that you kindly provided and made it my own! However, how do I actually make it so that when the user selects B, this function runs. I have this so far with the code you kindly provided above. elif answer == "b":
 print("Okay, lets start")